# Advice on automating datamining with Python

Tags: python, automation

I am a Biologist with a little programming experience in Python. One of my research methods involves profiling large gene lists using this database: https://david.ncifcrf.gov/ 
Can anyone advise me on whether it would be possible to do a keyword search of the output and return the gene name associated with the keyword? This is for the "Table" output which looks this: https://david.ncifcrf.gov/annotationReport.jsp?annot=59,12,87,88,30,38,46,3,5,55,53,70,79&currentList=0
There are also backend and api options.
All insight and advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there is an open API, you should try using that before looking into web scraping. Also https://david.ncifcrf.gov/annotationReport.jsp?annot=59,12,87,88,30,38,46,3,5,55,53,70,79&currentList=0 is not working for me.

Comment: Do API limitation satisfy your needs? Less than 400 genes, limit in url input to 2048 characters, 200 requests per day? As for otehr question with keyword search link you have provided doesn't seem to work (session expired)

Comment: FYI, the second link you gave is broken.

Comment: Exactly what you are trying to do isn't clear, but if it is possible at all it should be doable and even somewhat easy in Python, which is heavily used in bioinformatics.

Comment: Thank you for responding. My apologies for the broken link. It was an example of the "table" output using a test gene list provided by DAVID.

Comment: I'm going to try using SQL and Python to set up a table of the results from a CSV file. I think that this will enable  keyword searches and return the gene names associated with the search.This has been addressed on Stack before and I'll use it as a guide. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899088/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-python

Answer (score 0):

If there is an API which gives you all the data, you can automate almost everything associated with it. API's are either REST or SOAP so first you need to figure out what you need.

If the API is RESTful:

```
import urllib2, json

url = "https://mysuperapiurl.com/api-ws/api/port/" 
u = 'APIUsername'
p = 'APIPassword'

def encodeUserData(user, password):
    return "Basic " + (user + ":" + password).encode("base64").rstrip()
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.add_header('Authorization', encodeUserData(u, p))
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
j = json.load(res) # Here is all the data from the API
json_str= json.dumps(j) # this is the same as above as string
```

if the API is SOAP, it gets a bit harder. What I recommend is [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/). If that is not possible because your server is 2.6 or because several people are working on it, then use `suds`.

with suds an API call looks like this:

```
import logging, time, requests, re, suds_requests
from datetime import timedelta,date,datetime,tzinfo
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
from suds import null
from cStringIO import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

log_stream = StringIO()
logging.basicConfig(stream=log_stream, level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

WSDL_URL = 'http://213.166.38.97:8080/SRIManagementWS/services/SRIManagementSOAP?wsdl'

username='username'
password='password'
session = requests.session()
session.auth=(username, password)

def addSecurityHeader(client,username,password):
    security=Security()
    userNameToken=UsernameToken(username,password)
    security.tokens.append(userNameToken)
    client.set_options(wsse=security)

addSecurityHeader(client,username,password)

arg1 = "argument_1"
arg2 = "argument_2"

try:
    client.service.GetServiceById(arg1, arg2)
except TypeNotFound as e:
    print e
logresults = log_stream.getvalue()
```

You will receive xml in return so i use `beautifulsoup` to prettify the results:

```
soup = Soup(logresults)
print soup.prettify()
```

Ok so the API connection part is covered, where do you store your data, and where do you iterate over this data to perform a keyword search? In your database. I recommend `MySQLdb`. Setup your table and think about what information (that you collect from API)  you're going to store in which column.

```
def dbconnect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='password',
            db='mysuperdb'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

def getSQL():   
    db = dbconnect()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "select * from yoursupertable"
    dta = cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results

def dataResult():
    results = getSQL()
    for column in results:
        id = (column[1])
print dataResult()
```

So this is where you set your keywords (could also do it via another SQL) and compare the results you extract from your database with a list, dict, textfile or hardcoded keywords and define what to do if they match etc :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider voting it up/accepting as answer.